# Dart/Flutter FFI: Convert List to Array

Tags: c++, flutter, dart, ffi, dart-ffi

I have a struct that receives an array of type Float from a C++ library.

```
class MyStruct extends Struct{      
  @Array.multi([12])
  external Array<Float> states;
}
```

I am able to receive data and parse it in Dart.
Now I want to do the reverse. I have a `List<double>` which I want to assign to this struct and pass to C++.

The following cast fails at run time.

```
myStructObject.states = listObject as Array<Float>;
```

Neither Array class, nor List class has any related methods. Any idea on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to get around copying elements into FFI arrays.

```dart
for (var i = 0; i < listObject.length; i++) {
  my_struct.states[i] = listObject[i];
}
```

This may seem inefficient, but consider that depending on the specialization of `listObject`, the underlying memory layout of the data may differ significantly from the contiguous FFI layout, and so a type conversion sugar provided by Dart would likely also need to perform conversions on individual elements anyways (as opposed to just performing a single `memcpy` under the hood).

One possibility for closing the convenience gap would be to define an extension method. For example:

```dart
extension FloatArrayFill<T> on ffi.Array<ffi.Float> {
  void fillFromList(List<T> list) {
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      this[i] = list[i] as double;
    }
  }
}
```

Usage:

```dart
my_struct.states.fillFromList(list);
```

Note that a separate extension method would be need to be defined for each `ffi.Array<T>` specialization you want to do this for (`Array<Uint32>`, `Array<Double>`, `Array<Bool>`, etc.).
This is due to the `[]` operator being implemented through a separate extension method for each of these type specializations internally.

Comment: First approach I also had tried. It was giving me error. Second approach of extension method worked. Thank you.